# Is there anyway that I can get the table row with a specific td value with PHP or Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom

Say I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country<th>
            <th>Currency Name</th>
            <th>Currency Code</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Austria</td>
            <td>Euro</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>South Africa</td>
            <td>South African Rand</td>
            <td>ZAR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Greece</td>
            <td>Euro</td>
            <td>EUR</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the whole `<tr>` and contents containing `<td>ZAR</td>`? With Simple HTML DOM and PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '...'; // your HTML string

$html = str_get_html($string);

foreach ($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
    $flag = 0;
    foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td) {
        if ($tr->plaintext === 'ZAR') {
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($flag === 1) {
        echo $tr."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple isn't smart enough to do it directly, but with most decent libraries (phpquery?) you can do:

```
$doc->find('tr:has(td:contains("ZAR"))')
```